# Why does my CSS work with one id, but not with another IDENTICAL id?

Tags: html, css

When I do something like:

```css
#caterpillar {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="caterpillar">
  sample text
</div>
```

I get my white font and am happy. BUT for some reason, JUST CHANGING THE NAME OF THE DIV TAG:

```css
#centipede {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="centipede">
  sample text
</div>
```

In the same HTML template with the same CSS does NOT work and inspecting in chrome shows that it defaults to:

> ```
> element.style {
> }
> ```
>
> user agent stylesheet
>
> ```
> div {
>     display: block;
> }
> ```

and I do not get the desired effect. What could be happening? Why does it like one id name, but not the other ?

Comment: Try hard refreshing it *(Ctrl+F5)*

Comment: Check in your developer console if the html and css changes were accepted, otherwise press ctrl+ f5 or clear your browser-cache.

Comment: `font` is shorthand property which doesnt include the color of font.
color of font is controlled by `color` property of css.

more info on `font` property usage, refer: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp

Answer (score 5):

Neither of your examples work. `white` is not an acceptable value for `font` (well, it is if you are trying to use a font family with the name "white").

If you want to change the foreground colour, use the `color` property.

Comment: I think the aswer has been adited because i can´t see the error you are talking about. He is using `white` in `color`, not `font`.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't set the font color with the** `font` **shorthand**, you need to set it with `color: white`.

So the fact that it "does not work" in the second example is actually the expected behavior. The reason why it works with `#caterpillar` is propably because the color is inherited from a parent element, or there are some other CSS declarations for `#caterpillar` elsewhere, which may apply.

Take a look at the example below, it works with both ID's and the correct CSS

```css
#centipede{
    color: red;
}

#caterpillar {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="caterpillar">
    sample text
</div>

<div id="centipede">
    sample text
</div>
```

### What the `font` shorthand is actually for

Take a quick look at the [docs at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font), the font shorthand can be used to combine the following CSS properties:

#### mandatory

```
font-size
font-family
```

#### optional

```
font-style
font-variant
font-weight
line-height
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your browser cache to make sure your page is loading the latest version of it.

You could also try checking the sources in google developer console to make sure the latest is being loaded

Comment: wow this worked! Thank you! If the simplicity of my question didn't show it i'm new to web development. 

Are CSS stylesheets typically cached by default by browsers?

Comment: yes most popular browsers will cache both css and javascript. An easy way to get around this is to open a new incognito browser each time you run your code. if this has helped, please consider marking this as the accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `color` property instead of *font*

```
#caterpillar {
    color: white;
}
#centipede{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: if he/she wants to change the color of font dn we need to use color property. font property use for font size, font family and font color... ex: font: 14px arial #000; and for text color for ex: color: #ffffff;